# Hidden ID within Select Dropdown Box

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on another project that calls for a dropdown box to be populated with Salesman names.  I have setup the database to pass the `id` around, as opposed to the salesman's name.  I want to know if there is a way to include a "hidden" column within a dropdown box, and call the `id` as opposed to the `name`.

There could possibly be salesman with the same first and last name, so I can't use a UNIQUE column to help (by using jQuery to re-query the database based on `name`.

I'm open to suggestions if there might be a more appropriate way to do this.  Thanks in advance!

```
function getSalesmen() {
include 'scripts/mysql_login_pdo.php';

$query = "SELECT `id`, `fname`, `lname` " .
        "FROM `users` " .
        "ORDER BY `fname` ASC";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();

$salesman = '';

while ($row = $statement->fetchObject()) { 
    $fname = $row->fname;
    $lname = $row->lname;

    $salesman .= '<option>';
    $salesman .= $fname . ' ' . $lname; //This is where I'd like the ID to somehow be handled
    $salesman .= '</option>';
}
$db = null;
return $salesman;
}
```

Relevant section of index.php-

```
<li>
    <form method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>Salesman</li>
        <li><select id="salesman" name="salesman"><?php print getSalesmen(); ?>   </select></li>
        <li>Status</li>
        <li><select><?php print getStatus(); ?></select></li>
        <li><button type="button" id="search_a" name="search_a">Search</button><br />
            <button type="button" id="fill_all_a" name="fill_all_a">All Assigned Leads</button></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `value` attribute of your `option` tag

```
$salesman .= '<option value="'.$row->id.'">';
$salesman .= $fname . ' ' . $lname;
$salesman .= '</option>';
```

Now the `id` of the selected salesman will be posted.

Comment: Ahhhh... I remember this from an old VB program I wrote.  I will try and check back ASAP.  I think this is the right answer.

Comment: Thanks again.  That was it!  Waiting 5 more minutes to accept as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the "value" attribute (http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select#Examples)